# Aonde salvar dados no Angular aonde possam ser acessados de qualquer lugar e, ao alterá-los, atualizar componente

Tags: angular-8

Bom pessoal, minha questão pode ser bem idiota mesmo, mas é porque estou estudando sobre o Angular e como utiliza-lo.
Gostaria de saber aonde posso salvar dados que, ao alterá-lo, posso recuperar em qualquer lugar do sistema e também, atualizar o componente.
Por exemplo

Tenho uma pagina que é a home-page, dentro dela tenho o menu e a opção de selecionar a empresa aonde o usuário está logado.
Quando essa empresa for alterada no meu dropdown button, gostaria que o dados no meu  atualizassem.
Para tentar explicar melhor o que gostaria, vou postar o seguinte código da minha "home.html"

Aqui, na minha pagina home.html, eu seleciono um estabelecimento:

```
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menuEstab">
        <i class="material-icons md-36">store</i>
        {{estabelecimento.nomeFantasia}}
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menuEstab="matMenu">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let estab of estabelecimentos">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="changeEstab(estab)">
                <i class="material-icons md-18">business</i>
                {{estab.nomeFantasia}}
            </button>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-menu>
```

Hoje, ao selecionar qual o estabelecimento que quero utilizar para o usuário que está logado, eu salvo no sessionStorage:

```
  public changeEstab(estab: Estabelecimento) {
    this.estabelecimento = estab;
    sessionStorage.setItem(environment.currentEstab, JSON.stringify(estab));
  }
```

Porém, meu componente que está no centro da página, não sabe que o estabelecimento foi alterado, mas eu preciso saber.

```
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

Não sei se consegui me explicar direito, mas, qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Realmente não ficou muito claro sua questão man.

Comment: Pois é... o que eu quero é salvar os dados do usuário logado em um lugar e poder recuperar eles em qualquer outro componente, e, quando esses dados alterarem, que meu componente saiba que eu preciso atualizar para executar novas pesquisas.

Comment: Ou seja, o que você está querendo é um banco de dados.

Comment: @LeAndrade não... Eu quero que a minha aplicação tenha acesso aquela única instância, único objeto, como se fosse um Singleton. Algumas páginas dependem do conteúdo deste singleton e, quando ele alterar, essas páginas precisam ser atualizadas. Quando ele é alterado: Na minha mat-toolbar que é exibida em toda a aplicação há a possibilidade de alterar o emitente atual, ao alterar, as página que se encontra visível, deve atualizar com o estabelecimento selecionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pessoal, estou estudando por conta e acho que pulei algumas etapas antes de começar a implementar o software.
Para resolver o meu problema passei a utilizar [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/).
Essa abordagem é nova para mim, porém, depois de estudá-la bastante, implementei e resolveu o meu problema.

Obrigado a todos.